# Django Filter, where the newest price is the lowest, one to many rel

Tags: django, django-models

I got this super filter method, it gives me the products with the largest diff in the price.

But I only need products where the newest price is the lowest, can anyone help with that?

```
ps = Product.objects.filter(price__gt=1).annotate(dev=StdDev("price__price"), min_price=Min("price__price")).order_by('-dev')[:6]
```

Comment: What do you mean newest price? Does your price model have a date field?

Comment: ohh, sorry, yes .. the Price model has a datetime field called "created"

Comment: To make sure I have this correctly...  You still want to order the results by standard deviation.  And each product has many price.  So you want to order by the standard deviation of pricing on Products, excluding the products whose most recent price is not the lowest.  Is that accurate?

Comment: Humm .. let me explain in an other way ... I have Product model, a product can have a new prices every day,.. I need the products that has got a new price the last week and where the new price is lower then the last price it had ... and these products should be ordered by the product with heigest price diff en percent ;) .. hope it make sense??